# How to merge two tsibbles containing <aggregated>?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchy, fable-r, fabletools

I am trying to `merge()` two `tsibble` objects that contain aggregated values.

The reason I cannot use `cbind()` is because one of the aggregated `tsibble` objects contains values only for the "parent" level (i.e., upper-level) of the hierarchy, not the "child" level (to use the language from the `aggregated_key()` page on https://fabletools.tidyverts.org/reference/aggregate_key.html). In other words, one of the data sets has one fewer columns than the other.

A generalizable segment of code for the process I wish to perform is:

`Agg_TS_1 \<- as_tsibble(NonAgg_TS_1, index = Date, key = c("Parent", "Child")) %>% aggregate_key(Parent/Child, Value_1 = sum(Value1))`

`Agg_TS_2 \<- as_tsibble(NonAgg_TS_2, index = Date, key = "Parent") %>% aggregate_key(Parent, Value2 = sum(Value2))`

`merge(Agg_TS_1, Agg_TS_2, by = c("Date", "Parent"))`

However, the `merge()` function seems to not take aggregated values, as I get the error `` Error in `stop_vctrs()`: ! `levels.agg_vec()` not supported. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. `` each time I try to merge these.

Were this a data.frame or some other matrix containing no aggregation structure,  `merge()` would simply propagate `Value 2`  in the rows with that in which it is missing due to `Agg_TS_2` having no `Child` level in the hierarchy. However, I get the above-stated error.

Thoughts on how to remedy this?

Comment: Are you able to use a *_join() function from dplyr? For example, `left_join(Agg_TS_1, Agg_TS_2, by = c("Date", "Parent"))`? The `merge()` function seems a bit limited in requiring `levels` for an object class to join by, there is no such limitation with the `*_join()` functions.

Comment: It looks like that worked... my dplyr knowledge is limited! Thank you so much!